# Reset default track zoom in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic

I somehow made a false move, and Logic Pro X changed the default track zoom for a project to "half screen height". I can't imagine any use for that feature, but there it is. It's a long tedious manual process to fix all the tracks, and when I create a track stack in that project it's created at half the height of the screen, and must be manually fixed. If I enable automation on a track, I must manually resize the track header to show the automation controls, and then I must manually resize it back to normal after I hide automation. This is immensely tedious.

**Is there any way to make my project normal again?**

[I've read this page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12926?locale=en_US), and the part that claims to address my issue is simply wrong. The UI does not work that way.

The shift-drag suggestion in the documentation has no effect at all. The "Individual Track Zoom Reset for All Tracks" Key Command sounds promising, but it does the exact opposite: It sets all of my painstakingly corrected track heights back to half the height of the screen.

I found some practical-joke forum posts which suggested shift-double-click on the lower border of a track header. That of course sets all of my painstakingly corrected track heights back to half the height of the screen.

Another thing: I've had to redo volume automation several times on one particular track since this disaster befell the project. I do it, and it works for a while, and then the automation is just not there any more. When I moved the audio to a duplicate track, automation stopped working: Automation says minus infinity dB, yet I hear the track loud and clear. I don't need a fade there, so  just split the audio to work around the bug. But now it keeps turning the fader on the track to zero anyway, with no automation. Is this a known syndrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default track zoom is controlled by a little slider in the upper right corner just above the tracks area:

[image]

Clearly, I must have accidentally touched the mouse button while the pointer was above that slider. Once that slider is set to a sensible value, everything behaves normally, and shift-double-click on a track header border resizes all tracks to that sensible height.

However, they will never behave quite normally again. A sad and inexcusable mess on the Logic team's part.

The automation issue must be unrelated.

Comment: I believe there is a keyboard shortcut that triggers it too, because I’ve had this happen before while attempting to use a different shortcut.

Comment: I have been losing my mind trying to find this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's Support document "[Zoom tracks in Logic Pro](https://support.apple.com/guide/logicpro/zoom-tracks-lgcpc79f5bcd/mac)":

> 1. In Logic Pro, move the pointer to the bottom-left corner of a track. (**Not a region, the track.)** [notation mine]
>
>    The pointer changes to a pair of up- and down-pointing arrows.
> 2. Press and hold Shift while dragging up or down. (Or simply click to reset all tracks to same vertical height)

Comment: "Or simply click to reset all tracks to same vertical height" does not work. I mentioned that in my post. Trust nothing in Apple documentation.